# Flink - producing to kinesis not working

Tags: scala, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to run a simple program which reads from one kinesis stream, does a trivial transformation, and writes the result to another kinesis stream.

Running locally on Flink 1.4.0 (this is the version supported on EMR currently, so no way of upgrading).

Here is the code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  val consumerConfig = new Properties()
  consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")
  consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST")

  val kinesisMaps = env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](
    "source-stream", new SimpleStringSchema, consumerConfig))

  val jsonMaps = kinesisMaps.map { jsonStr => JSON.parseFull(jsonStr).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]] }
  val values = jsonMaps.map(jsonMap => jsonMap("field_name"))

  values.print()

  val producerConfig = new Properties()
  producerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")

  val kinesisProducer = new FlinkKinesisProducer[String](new SimpleStringSchema, producerConfig)
  kinesisProducer.setFailOnError(true)
  kinesisProducer.setDefaultStream("target-stream")
  kinesisProducer.setDefaultPartition("0")

  values.addSink(kinesisProducer)

  // execute program
  env.execute("Flink Kinesis")
}
```

If I comment out the producing code, the program runs as expected and prints the correct values.

As soon as I add the producer code, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.DaemonException: The child process has been shutdown and can no longer accept messages.
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.add(Daemon.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer.addUserRecord(KinesisProducer.java:477)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisProducer.invoke(FlinkKinesisProducer.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction.invoke(SinkFunction.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:549)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:504)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:608)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:569)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:809)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:549)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:504)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:809)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:549)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:504)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:809)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.emitRecordAndUpdateState(KinesisDataFetcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.deserializeRecordForCollectionAndUpdateState(ShardConsumer.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.run(ShardConsumer.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea what's the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is an issue with the old version of Amazon KPL which is used in Flink 1.4.

There are at least two possible solutions for this:

1. Upgrade to Flink version 1.5.
   You can still use it on EMR, if you install it as described here, under the section Custom EMR Installation:
   https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/deployment/aws.html
2. When building the Kinesis connector for Flink 1.4, you can build it with newer AWS dependencies: I've cherry-picked the `aws` dependency changes in `pom.xml` of the connector from 1.5, and built the connector with them. Looks like it's working as expected.

Comment: isnt Flink version is determined by what branch we build the connector from https://github.com/apache/flink

Comment: Yes, but you can modify the flink branch you use and change it to a newer KPL dependency, while leaving the rest of the code intact - at least for me, it worked.

Comment: And another option, like mentioned above, is to run a custom Flink version on EMR, and not only the ones AWS provides you.
In any case, the newest EMR versions also include Flink 1.5.

Comment: Hey @Alexey can you take a look at this repo? https://github.com/freedomkwok/StreamingAlertSystem/tree/master/Practice/StreamingAlertSystem, I built flink under version, 1.5, but when I debug the project, nothing get back from Kinesis, even within Fiddler4, I dont see any traffic send to kinesis, however I do see it try to get the shardIterator, but just nothing happen after

Comment: @Ricc first of all my problem was with Flink 1.4, in 1.5 the kinesis worked fine, so I don't think you need to take 1.6 connecter - just use version 1.5 for everything.
Also my problem was with the producer, and yours seems to be with the consumer?

Add some sort of `.print()` at the end of your logic to actually trigger the computation.

I didn't use a deserialization schema, just used json data coming from kinesis (and then parsed it in the lambda).